# Rearange TBindNavigator Buttons

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am using FireDac controls to connect with my db.

To navigate through the result sets i then use TBindNavigator.

This is a very handy component. However it lacks support for rearanging the buttons.

Here is an image of the control:

[image]

What i try to achieve is:

[image]

I downloaded the trial Version of TMS components and even their control (https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/dban.asp) isn't able to rearanche the buttons.

I am wondering if this is possible?

Comment: Obviously, it ought to be possible, it just depends how much trouble you're prepared to go to in order to do it.  I'd be surprised if either component has this ability built-in (because I've not seen this feature being asked for before, nor for TDBNavigator which has been around 20 years now), so you would probably have to modify the source and use that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you need to create class inherited from dbnavigator, like e.g. :

```
type TNewDBNavigator = class(TDBNavigator);
```

It's needed because Buttons in TDBNavigator are protected.

Buttons are declared as:

```
Buttons: array[TNavigateBtn] of TNavButton;
```

And their order:

```
TNavigateBtn = 
(nbFirst, nbPrior, nbNext, nbLast, nbInsert, 
 nbDelete, nbEdit, nbPost, nbCancel, nbRefresh);
```

If You had trouble with "hacking" VCL components, there is 
nice article at delphi.about.com:
[At this link](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/l/aa082603a.htm)

The other approach would be creating a set of custom buttons and modify their behaviur the way You want them to.

Best regards